# copy a directory into another directory and create intermediate directories

Tags: cp

I would like to copy the whole **/usr/share/zoneinfo/** directory into /var/www/clients/client1/web5/./**usr/share/zoneinfo/**. (The `/./` is added for clarity and formatting purposes)

The directory /var/www/clients/client1/web5/ exists, but the underlying **usr/share/zoneinfo** directory doesn't.

Is there a way to do this with a single command or do I have to call `mkdir -p` first ?

I thought `cp --parents` would do just that, but it seems it only works when copying a single file, not a whole directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync -a --relative` did the trick.

```
rsync -a --relative /usr/share/zoneinfo/ /var/www/clients/client1/web5/
```

Credit goes to [unix_ninja](https://twitter.com/unix_ninja) on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/unix_ninja/status/1293204649659576321)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are specifying a destination location of `/var/www/clients/client1/web5/./usr/share/zoneinfo/`, `cp` will first look to make sure that directory exists to write files into.  So yes, you will need to create the directory first.  However, if `/var/www/clients/client1/web5/./usr/share/` is already present, you should be able to:

```
cp -pr /usr/share/zoneinfo /var/www/clients/client1/web5/./usr/share/zoneinfo
```

as the destination directory exists to write the `zoneinfo` directory into.